# How to use localStorage to store user id

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to use localStorage to store user id. Then fetch the user id if it exists and if it does not exist then create it using the google's analytics.js and store it.

To get clientId I am using the following code:-

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
  console.log(tracker.get('clientId'));
});
```

The clientId generated here should be stored as an user id.

Comment: could you not just use cookies?

Comment: No cookies or sessions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to set your ClientID,

```
localStorage.setItem("clientId","someID")
```

to get,

```
if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty("clientId")) {
    cli_id = localStorage.getItem("clientId")
}
else {
    cli_id = localStorage.setItem("clientId","someID") // here someid from your google analytics fetch
}
console.log(cli_id)
```

Comment: Could you give a detailed code snippet to verify the existence of the previously generated id.

Comment: @ShashishekharHasabnis answer has been edited. check now