# How to use variables from two different HTML pages in JS

Tags: javascript, forms

I was making a easy form site and when the person submits the form, it sends them to a thank you page. I am trying to display the name they submitted in the thank you page using:

```
var name = document.querySelector(".name").value;

document.getElementById("savedText").innerHTML = `Thank you for signing up ${name}!`;
```

But it isn't working.

Comment: What is the error message? What is the back-end language you are using? Without passing the form contents to the thank you page, it's not going to be possible to simply transfer the name variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use localStorage to store user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585987/how-to-use-localstorage-to-store-user-id)

Comment: At least three potential issues.  1) this logic runs before the HTML exists, 2) either an element with a class of `name` or an id of `savedText` do not exist, or 3) the element with class `name` does not have a value.

Comment: @quotsa42 What do you mean? Another piece of code in my form file ensures that all parts of the form are answered.